# How to run django-sentry on windows?

Tags: python, django, error-logging

I have an issue to run django-sentry on windows. I have read this issue [github.com/dcramer/django-sentry/issues/245](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry/issues/245). I skipped 'python-daemon>=1.6' during manual installation of django-sentry. But when I run command "sentry start", I get "ImportError: No module named daemon.daemon".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you read that issue, the point is that sentry **requires** python-deamon, which happens to be *nix only. In other words, sentry currently doesn't work on windows.

that's like saying "i know my car needs an engine to run, but since i could't find a suitable one, i just didn't put one in. and now i don't understand why my car doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

This just affects the '[Running a Sentry Server](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/v1.13.5/install/index.html#running-a-sentry-server)' setup and not the '[Integrated Setup](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/v1.13.5/install/index.html#integrated-setup)'. I believe this has been made more explicit in the 2.0 alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of sentry (3.x, 5.x) are not depending on python-daemon, thus they can be run on windows...